# onMeasure and onLayout of child views are not called after requestLayout on their parent

Tags: android, android-custom-view, onmeasure

I'm trying understanding how Android measures and lays out views. I created a sample app with custom views and view groups.

**CustomViewGroup**

```
public class CustomViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "CustomViewGroup";

    public CustomViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,
                getTag() + " " +
                        "onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec=%d, heightMeasureSpec%d)",
                widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec
        ));

        final int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
                // Make or work out measurements for children here (MeasureSpec.make...)
                measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,
                getTag() + " " +
                        "onLayout(changed=%b, left=%d, top=%d, right=%d, bottom=%d)",
                changed, left, top, top, right, bottom
        ));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, getTag() + " " + "onDraw");
    }
}
```

**CustomView**

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "CustomView";

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,
                getTag() + " " +
                "onLayout(changed=%b, left=%d, top=%d, right=%d, bottom=%d)",
                changed, left, top, top, right, bottom
        ));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, getTag() + " " +"onDraw");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,
                getTag() + " " +
                "onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec=%d, heightMeasureSpec=%d)",
                widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec
        ));
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private View mCustomGroup1;
    private View mCustomGroup2;
    private View mContainer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("MainAct", "onCreate");
        mCustomGroup1 = findViewById(R.id.requestLayout);
        mCustomGroup2 = findViewById(R.id.requestLayout2);
        mContainer = findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.requestLayoutBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCustomGroup1.requestLayout();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.requestLayoutBtn2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCustomGroup2.requestLayout();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.requestLayoutContBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mContainer.requestLayout();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ru.dmitriev.squareorderedlayout.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/requestLayoutBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="requestLayout" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/requestLayoutBtn2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="requestLayout2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/requestLayoutContBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="requestLayoutCont" />

    <ru.dmitriev.squareorderedlayout.CustomViewGroup
        android:id="@+id/requestLayout"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#7f7"
        android:tag="CustomVieGroup1">

        <ru.dmitriev.squareorderedlayout.CustomView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:tag="CustomView11" />

        <ru.dmitriev.squareorderedlayout.CustomView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:tag="CustomView12" />
    </ru.dmitriev.squareorderedlayout.CustomViewGroup>

    <ru.dmitriev.squareorderedlayout.CustomViewGroup
        android:id="@+id/requestLayout2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#f77"
        android:tag="CustomVieGroup2">

        <ru.dmitriev.squareorderedlayout.CustomView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:tag="CustomView21" />

        <ru.dmitriev.squareorderedlayout.CustomView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:tag="CustomView22" />

    </ru.dmitriev.squareorderedlayout.CustomViewGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

When the activity starts, `onMeasure`, `onLayout` and `onDraw` are called on the view groups tagged `CustomVieGroup1` and `CustomVieGroup2`. Each view group calls these methods on their children. It's OK. I understand it.

When I call `requestLayout` on the view group tagged CustomVieGroup**1**, `onMeasure`, `onLayout` and `onDraw` are called on CustomVieGroup**1**. The group calls these methods on their children. I understand it.

When I call `requestLayout` on the view group tagged CustomVieGroup**2**, `onMeasure`, `onLayout` and `onDraw` are called on CustomVieGroup**2**. The group calls these methods on their children. I understand it as well.

But when I call `requestLayout` on the view with id `activity_main`, `onMeasure` and `onLayout` are not called on `CustomVieGroup1` or `CustomVieGroup2`. Why? I expected that `onMeasure`, `onLayout` and `onDraw` will be called on both `CustomVieGroup1` and `CustomVieGroup2` (i.e. the cgildren of the view with id `activity_main`)

According to the [documentation of requestLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout()):

> This will schedule a layout pass of the view tree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`requestLayout()` will cause the `onLayout()` method of the `LinearLayout` (@id/activity_main) to execute.  However, there is no guarantee that the `LinearLayout` will then re-layout its children; it really depends on its implementation.  For example, your `LinearLayout` width/height is set to `match_parent`.  When the `LinearLayout` is laid-out a second time, its width and height wont change because its size it is based on its parent size, not its children.  Because its layout is not based on its children, there is no need for `LinearLayout` to re-layout its children.  This is why invalidating a layout of nearly any `ViewGroup` whose size matches its parent will not cause that layout's children to be laid-out.

You should be able to confirm this be changing your `LinearLayout` (@id/activity_main) to 'wrap_content'.  By doing this, the layout's size becomes dependent on its children, so it will need to re-layout its children.  This will cause your custom view layout methods to be called.  Hope this helps,

Comment: Absolutely correct! Changing `match_parent` to `wrap_content` makes the difference